# splash screen with animation to form a word

Tags: android

hello everyone I want to do splash screen with animation of the image that comes from the top to the middle one after the other of screen and then do a little animation for example image img1 from top to middle of the screen and then img2 from high towards the middle of the screen is this place to the right of image img1 so on....at the end, images form a word
here is the code that I use

```
   final int TIME_OUT = 400;

    final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    final ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
    final ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img3);
    final ImageView imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img4);
    final ImageView imageView5 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img5);
    final ImageView imageView6 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img6);
    final ImageView imageView7 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img7);
    final ImageView imageView8 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img8);
    final ImageView imageView9 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img9);
    final ImageView imageView10 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img10);
    final ImageView imageView11 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img11);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, TIME_OUT);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, TIME_OUT * 2);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, TIME_OUT * 3);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, TIME_OUT * 4);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, TIME_OUT * 5);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, TIME_OUT * 6);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, TIME_OUT * 7);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, TIME_OUT * 8);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, TIME_OUT * 9);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, TIME_OUT * 10);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, TIME_OUT * 11);
    splashTread=new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                // Splash screen pause time
                while (waited < 3000) {
                    sleep(180);
                    waited += 90;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                splash.this.finish();

            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                splash.this.finish();
            }

        }
    };
    splashTread.start();

}
```

}

Comment: I recommend you to use a [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this awesome third party library. 
[Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android)

Create a After Effects Adobe animation file as per your requirement, then use this library to parse and use it in your app.

Comment: thanks.is there a link that explains how this library is used because I'm a beginner in this field

Comment: Check out the library sample app. And, for animation, try searching for Adobe After effects animation tutorial. Kindly upvote and mark as correct if my solution helped you.